# reg: some users not able to edit query results in ms access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

We have a split MS Access database. The front end was distributed among us. And some users are able to run queries and edit query results without a hitch. But a few others are not able to edit the query results. The query runs fine for them and they are able to see the results in MS Access. But editing any field is not possible.

Could anyone advise me on how this can have happened. I have primary keys on all the tables on which the queries are based. And there are no joins in my queries. Each query runs on a single table.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

With regards,
Manus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. The back end database was on a network drive where some of the users had write access but not all. Silly of me not to look there first. So basically the users who couldn't edit were the ones with no write access on the shared drive in which the back end of the database was kept.